# What are some fast alternatives to dynamic time warping?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, clustering

I am planning to cluster a great amount of time series of different lengths into groups without using the method Dynamic Time Warping, but something else which gives a little better execution time and results. What's your opinion?

---

I mean that I need an algorithm, exept from DTW but a litter better than it, that measures similarity between temporal sequences -times series of different lengths- and then performs clustering using distance measures techniques as criterion. Then I will be able to perform forecasting to time series according to the train sets time series which I have clustered

Comment: Computing the DTW requires O ( N 2 ) in general. Fast techniques for computing DTW include PrunedDTW,[1] SparseDTW,[2] FastDTW,[3] and the MultiscaleDTW.[4][5] A common task, retrieval of similar time series, can be accelerated by using lower bounds such as LB_Keogh[6] or LB_Improved.[7] In a survey, Wang et al. reported slightly better results with the LB_Improved lower bound than the LB_Keogh bound, and found that other techniques were inefficient.[8] from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Comment: Other distance measures to use would be Euclidean Distance (ED) or Longest common subsequence (LCSS).

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by "clustering", what is your expectation on "better execution time" and for the result?

Comment: I mean that I need an algorithm, exept from DTW but a litter better than it, that measures similarity between temporal  sequences -times series of different lengths- and then performs clustering using distance measures techniques as criterion. Then I will be able to perform forecasting to time series according to the train sets time series which I have clustered.

Answer (score 4):

Better results that DTW? For the problems of time series classification, there is nothing significantly better than DTW, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01711

As for "better execution time", DTW with a warping constraint and LB_keogh is fast enough for virtually any task.

See http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can always approximate your data if scalability is an issue.

Also similarity search *indexes* can speed up many algorithms.